# Stuck on question that uses lists and functions and iterating over lists

Tags: python

The 2 different types of characters have `names`, `race` and `health` assigned to them. `True = orcs`, `False = goblins`

Im not sure how to make this function display all races or just 1 and also show the name and health assigned to them

for example if 2 is entered to show all listed goblins how do i make a loop to do that. Full question below :

display_characters(character_list, display_type)
This function will take the list of character objects and a display_type as a parameter and will output
the contents of the list to the screen. If the display type is 0, all characters will be displayed to the
screen. If the display type is 1, only orcs will be displayed to the screen. If the display type is 2,
only goblins will be displayed to the screen

You must use
a loop in your solution.

Thank you in advance (beginner)

I've tried messing with some for loops iterating over all variables in character_list but unsure how to approach it and think im doing it wrong

```
def display_characters(character_list, display_type):
    for x in character_list:
        if display_type == 0 :
            print(character_list)
        elif display_type == 1 :

        elif display_type == 2:
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of your loop.

```
def display_characters(character_list, display_type):
    if not display_type:
        return character_list
    else:
        return [x for x in character_list if x[1] == display_type]

char = [['a', 'orc', 'stats'],['b', 'orc', 'stats'],['d', 'orc', 'stats'],['e', 'goblin', 'stats']]

print(display_characters(char, 'goblin'))
```

Comment: I was just assisting with his code, not doing his project for him.  Plus yours doesn't find orc or goblin so not sure how yours is better.

Comment: That is not what it says.  Being insulting isn't productive.  He did not say that race was True or False, he said he was sending the display_type as true and false.  Which is a broken design because he needs at LEAST 3 options.  All races, or a select race.  Under your impression a result would be IMPOSSIBLE.  My solution handles all cases, and updated cases without the need to change the function.